How is this video playback issue called?
Basically, I need help with finding correct terms for google. Personally, I'd call it 'throwbacks' but it seems too generic. Google is stuffed with links to movies and music clips of the same name; I can't figure out anything useful.
The issue looks like this: when running a certain live camera feed in the browser, the moving objects like cars and people jump back sometimes. It's especially noticeable when a car takes a turn, like its position was extrapolated from the direction of its movement and then updated to what actually happened.
So, what's the correct term?

It might be termed frame-dropping, pausing or stuttering.
A common cause is insufficient bandwidth, whether due to a slow connection or slow CPU/GPU. The video is buffered (held in cache), and when it changes too fast, the last frame is kept on screen while a few frames are skipped to catch up with the accompanying audio.
Some video apps such as VLC and Firefox have settings to adjust the video buffer size. Try increasing the buffer to reduce dropping frames.

Sorry for a possible misunderstanding, but it does not look to be the case. It's not stuttering, pausing or frame drop. The video gets thrown back in time for some reason.
